# Choose a Image from Gallery and send to another Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, bitmap

So I have an app and in this app in the first activity you choose a image from the gallery or take a photo with the camera.

Then there are a few Activitys between the Activity I needed the picture. So how can I send this image choosen in the first Activity to the activity i need it in? I thought I can make it like these putExtra() Method but I was reading that I costs a lot of memory to send bitmaps to another Activity.

My Goal is to edit this Image as a bitmap in the last activity!

So who got some solutions how i can fix this Problem?! Any Ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Send a `Uri` pointing to the image to the other activity, via `setData()` on the `Intent`, along with `addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION`).

Comment: and decode it to a bitmap in the last Activity?

Comment: Yes. This assumes that the intermediate activities do not need the bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

I use Library called sandriosCamera, it is very costumizable and works in that it less than android 5.0 too (So use CameraApi and CameraApi2). It includes recent image in gallery picker and too shows a preview of the image doing a matrix (Rotate) when the image has an incorrect orientation.
Read this in android arsenal and look the github for the library code https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4962
Then I pass with a `putExtra()` the image path (because of the image is temporal and then I need to `getExtra()` of the intent to have the path of the image in my SendActivity.
Hope it helps with all your problems.
PD: I recommend to download the master.zip and not to import as a library with gradle, because you can costumize if you want (But then you need to fix problems). Before of import to the gradle or manual I recommend too to update all your android tools, max version, etc.